# S.M.A.R.T. diagnostics recommends firmware upgrade

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, firmware, smart

I have an Ubuntu server with a RAID-6 array.

```
3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I was checking out the S.M.A.R.T. diagnostics for the drives and then this output caught my eye:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-27-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1CH166
<lines removed>
Firmware Version: CC24
<lines removed>
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jun  1 14:02:23 2014 CEST

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive may be available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en
```

Is it a good idea to do the firmware upgrade? The Seagate website is not very informative, what benefits might I expect?

Apart from the obvious backup, what should I be aware of considering that the disks are in a RAID?

Comment: You should not upgrade the firmware to any device unless the newer version either add a new feature or fixes a problem you experience.

Comment: @Ramhound : If you make that into an answer I can vote for it.